# How to divert Future failure in Akka stream to a separate sink?

Tags: scala, error-handling, akka-stream

I have a stream with following structure

```
val source = Source(1 to 10)

val flow1 = Flow[Int].mapAsyncUnordered(2){ x =>
    if (x != 7) Future.successful(x)
    else Future.failed(new Exception(s"x has failed"))

val flow2 = Flow[Int].mapAsyncUnordered(2){ x =>
    if (x != 4) Future.successful(x)
    else Future.failed(new Exception(s"x has failed"))

val sink = Sink.fold(List[Int])((xs, x: Int) => x :: xs)
val errorSink = Sink.fold(List[Exception])((errs ,err: Exception) => err :: errs)
```

My question:
How should I construct the divertTo function to send all exceptions to errorSink?
Any suggestion on how to get the error object with information on which stage it failed would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend modelling your errors as a proper type so that you have a `Flow[Either[CustomErrorType, Int]]` for instance and then you can use `divertTo` with a predicate that looks at whether you have a `Left` or `Right`.
Or maybe use `recover` in combination.

See this interesting article: https://bszwej.medium.com/akka-streams-error-handling-7ff9cc01bc12

Comment: I agree with this. This may also help: https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/akka-streams-exception-handling/6557

Comment: Thank you so much! In my project, the flow1 and flow2 call to other services, which return Future. Therefore, I have to use Await.result to transform to Either. I think it's not so good to use Await. So still thinking about it.

Comment: You can have a `Future[Either[Error, X]]` in your `mapAsync`. As you currently have `Future[Int]` in `mapAsync` but the flow is of type `Flow[Int]` (the future "wait" is managed by the `mapAsync`.

Comment: Anyway @Levis's answer is more detailed. It's the same idea but with `Try` instead of `Either`.

Comment: oh now I see your point. Let me try it! thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`Future` encodes both asynchronicity and can-fail.  You'll need to separate the asynchronicity and can-fail.

`Try`, for instance, is an encoding of can-fail.

Meanwhile, `mapAsyncUnordered` only emits successes (you can use a supervision strategy to decide not to fail on a failed future, but that will drop the failures not emit them).

It seems that you want to accumulate a list of failures (given the use of `Sink.fold`).  Since that list of failures is only accessible to the outside world through the materialized value, you'll want to use `divertToMat` instead of `divertTo`.

From this, the logical solution is:

```scala
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.util.{ Failure, Success, Try }

// Returns a future which is only a failure on fatal exceptions
def liftToFutTry[T](fut: Future[T])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Try[T]] =
  fut.map(Success(_))
    .recoverWith {
      case ex => Future.successful(Failure(ex))
    }

// for some reason we want a List[Exception] rather than List[Throwable]
val errorSink: Sink[Try[Int], Future[List[Exception]]] =
  Flow[Try[Int]]
    .mapConcat { t =>
      t.failed.get match {
        case ex: Exception => List(ex)
        case _ => Nil
      } : List[Exception]
    }
    .toMat(Sink.fold(List.empty[Exception]) { (exes, ex) => ex :: exes })(Keep.right)

// materializes as a future of the exceptions which failed in mapAsyncUnordered
val flow1: Flow[Int, Int, Future[List[Exception]]] =
  Flow[Int]
    .mapAsyncUnordered(2) { x =>
      val fut =
        if (x != 7) Future.successful(x)
        else Future.failed(new Exception(s"$x has failed (equaled 7)"))

      liftToFutTry(fut)
    }
    .divertToMat(errorSink, _.isFailure)(Keep.right)  // propagate the failures
    .map { successfulTry => successfulTry.get }
```

If you have two `Flow`s like this and you want to compose them, you'd do

```scala
// materialized value is (list of failures from flow1, list of failures from otherFlow
val both: Flow[Int, Int, (Future[List[Exception]], Future[List[Exception]])]
  flow1
    .viaMat(flow2)(Keep.both)

// materialized value is:
//  (
//    (
//      list of failures from flow1,
//      list of failures from otherFlow
//    ),
//    list of ints which passed through both flow1 and otherFlow
//  )
both.toMat(sink)(Keep.both) : Sink[Int, ((Future[List[Exception]], Future[List[Exception]]), Future[List[Int]])]
```

There are other ways to encode can-fail: e.g. you could use `Either` from the standard library.

Accumulating a `Future[List[_]]` may be questionable; note that the `Future`s won't be complete until the stream finishes.

Comment: haha there is no reason I prefer exception rather than a throwable. Anyway, this is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much!